# passing parameter to java script function ha no sense

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a link in a C# page, which on its click event runs a JavaScript onclick
The problem is when I change my JavaScript function to take a parameter, and I pass a parameter to this function static or dynamic, it doesn't work; it worked before I made the JavaScript function take a parameter.

The function is

```
function  moon(url)
{
    alert(url);
    window.location.href = url;
    alert("mon");
}
```

The code that calls the JavaScript function is

```
string mylink="..............";

material_data += "<td><a onclick='moon("+mylink+")'><img style='margin-top:5px;' width='20' height='20' src='../Contents/images/trash.png' title='delete album' /></a></td>";
```

Comment: this code is not working now, when the function has no parameter , it is working well > so, i need to solve my syntax. how????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're doing with this, but the reason it's not working is you need quotes around `mylink`

```
material_data += "<td><a onclick=\"moon('"+mylink+"')\"><img style='margin-top:5px;' width='20' height='20' src='../Contents/images/trash.png' title='delete album' /></a></td>";
```

That should actually work whether your `material_data +=` line is `JavaScript` or `C#`

Answer (score 1):

The question makes half sense and from what I understand the problem is the value you have for **mylink**. 
In your case I would suggest you use HyperLink control. Set the NavigateUrl accordingly. And set Target Property as parent.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink1" ImageUrl="~/Contents/images/trash.png" Target="_parent" runat="server" />
```

In code-behind you set the NavigateUrl like:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = mylink;
```